# jquerytools overlay function doesnt seem to exist

Tags: jquery, overlay

im using overylay from jquery tools, however I cant seem to get the example working

I get the following error:

"$("a[rel='overlay']").overlay(function() {" is not a function

In my HTML file i have the jquery/overlay package then i have "common.js" where I call overlay for all links with rel=overlay

```
    // jQuery functions go in here
if (typeof(jQuery) != "undefined") {
    /* Pops overlay windows for links with rel="overlay" */
     $(function() {
        $("body").append("<div class='overlay' id='overlay'><div class='overlay-wrap'></div></div>");
        // if the function argument is given to overlay, it is assumed to be the onBeforeLoad event listener 
        $("a[rel='overlay']").overlay(function() {  
            // grab wrapper element inside content 
            var wrap = this.getContent().find("div.overlay-wrap"); 
            // load only for the first time it is opened 
            if (wrap.is(":empty")) { 
                wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href")); 
            } 
        }); 
    });
}
```

any idea where im going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Are you completely sure the overlay JavaScript file is included in your page?

I was checking this [Minimal setup tutorial](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/index.html) and the link that they provide for the [JavaScript file](http://static.flowplayer.org/js/jquery.overlay-1.0.4.min.js) is broken...

I recommend you to download and host the .js and .css files on your server...

Check the [minimal setup](http://jsbin.com/igudu) working with [another file](http://static.flowplayer.org/js/tools/1.0.2/xxxxxx_xxxx/jquery.tools.min.js)...

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to add that the jQuery Tools auto-generator (http://flowplayer.org/tools/download/index.html#combine) seems to be generating JS files with errors.  If I download a working file directly off a working overlay demo page, then the overlay effect works, otherwise, I just get errors mentioned like "overlay is not a function".